# Java: Render Undefined for Type Font

Tags: java

i'm working on a game and came across this error. Here's the main class:

(NVM, the codeI used won't import right. Here's a pastebin:)
http://pastebin.com/E1tucjV2

I've been trying to figure it out fir a while, and I'm new to java, so If I'm making a foolish mistake, please tell me.

Additional info:
The main class and the Font class are in different packages

Edit:
ALSO: I'm trying to render text.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean this line?

```
Font.render("Hello World! 0157", screen, 0, 0, Color.red);
```

Well, Font has no `render` method as can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

So either you have the wrong import or you have the wrong way of rendering.

To output text to a `Canvas` you use for example:

```
g.drawString("abc", 25, 25);
```

To set a font you use:

```
g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```